# SSH fingerprint change after ubuntu update (Azure only)

Tags: azure

After upgrading my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine hosted on Azure (previous update was two weeks ago on Feb. 22nd), it now warns me about changed server SSH key when I try to connect to it.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
```

I am ruling out the Ubuntu update triggering this change because this happened with my (only) Azure machine, but not the rest of about a dozen Linux servers that run either locally or on AWS with nearly identical configuration that were updated at the same time. I have also checked the host key algorithm as reported by `ssh -v` and it is unchanged (ECDSA-SHA2-NISTP256).

Is there anything specific about the way Azure handles SSH connections, or something particular about the Ubuntu image provided by Azure that could have led to the change in the server key?

P.S. I am downloading the VHD to check the machine locally, but this will take at least 24 hours with my connection. I was just wondering, maybe somebody has run into the same issue before.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the keys were regenerated by cloud-init. As far as I can tell it was due to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1551419

I would like to be able to provide a less painful solution than downloading the VHD and checking the server fingerprint, but unfortunately the Azure portal still displays the fingerprint for the original key that was created when the instance was first provisioned.